# Configure package button disabled with admin clone profile

Tags: managed-package, administration

To do some manual testing I cloned the admin profile and assigned it to a newly created user (User License  Salesforce)
I have installed a package where I normally see a configure package link.
When I log in with that new user I do not see a configure package link.
Shouldn't this user also see a configure package link on the installed packages page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Download AppExchange Packages` checkbox was unchecked on the admin clone profile.
After checking it the user can also see the configure package link.